# push_back in empty integer vector is filling it with unexpected values?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

```
    int main()
    {
    using namespace std;
    int n = 5,input;
    vector<int> N(n);
    vector<int> S;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>input;
        N.push_back(input);
    }

        cin>>Q;
        for(auto const& value: N)
        {
            if(value<Q)
            {
                S.push_back(value);
                N.erase(remove(N.begin(), N.end(), value), N.end());

            }
        }
...
```

This code first pushes the values entered by user into N vector and then within for loop, if the value of the element in N vector is less than Q, then it will push that element into the empty vector S and removes that element from vector N.
For example:

```
N vector : 21 9 5 8 10
Q = 10
```

Now after the first iteration :

```
N vector : 21 10
S vector : 0 9 8 9 5 8
```

But the expected S vector is :

```
S vector : 9 5 8
```

Why I'm getting unexpected S vector values?

Comment: maybe you fail to understand that  `vector<int> N(n);` fills the vector with `n` zeroes?

Comment: @M.M I'm talking about `vector<int> S;`.

Comment: vector::erase invalidates iterators, the range based for loop uses iterators - you have undefined behaviour

Comment: What you're trying to accomplish requires no loops.  Three algorithm function calls is all you need.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie May you name those three algorithm function names please?

Comment: Read up on `std::partition` and `std::stable_partition`.

Comment: @RichardCritten But I have to remove that value from N vector. What should I do?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm unable to get it that how to form my solution using this? May you please provide a sample code through answer or comment, please?

Comment: What does "partition" do?  It separates the "bad" items in the vector from the good items.  Then it is just a matter of copying the bad items to the other vector, and then doing one single erase of the bad items in the old vector.  See my answer.

Comment: @ddlj How could N vector consist of `21 9 5 8 10` in your code sample?

Comment: @ddj -- The bottom line is that if you're writing loops that seems to do something that's been done many times before, there are STL algorithm or set of algorithm functions that do the job.  You just have to think about what you're really doing on a high-level, which is partitioning, copying, erasing, exactly as the answer I posted does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is to remove items from a vector that satisfies a certain condition, and add those removed items to another vector, using the STL algorithm functions will do the job instead of writing loops:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> N = { 32, 10, 22, 100, 210, 1};
    std::vector<int> S;
    int Q = 100;

    // partition the items
    auto it = std::stable_partition(N.begin(), N.end(), [&](int n) { return n < Q;});

    // copy items from left partition to the vector
    std::copy(N.begin(), it, std::back_inserter(S));

    // erase items in left partition
    N.erase(N.begin(), it);
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/t1SGbI)

The whole idea is to use a partitioning algorithm.  In this case, I used [std::stable_partition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition) to return an iterator that divides the partitioned vector.

The partition point is determined by the predicate (`n < Q`).  Anything to the left of the partition satisfies `n < Q`, else the values are placed on the right of the partition.